# ChannelHandlerContext setAttachment Method

Tags: java, netty

So in the Netty 3.x libraries, the class ChannelHandlerContext has a method named setAttachment. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to exist in the new 4.0 libraries. I was wondering if there is a way to put attachment like on the older libraries.

Answer (score 4):

After doing a little research I found the following:

The javadocs for the interface [org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html) in the version `3.2` states

> **Storing stateful information**
>
> [setAttachment(Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html#setAttachment%28java.lang.Object%29) and [getAttachment()](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html#getAttachment%28%29) allow you to store and access stateful information that is related with a handler and its context. Please refer to [ChannelHandler](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html) to learn various recommended ways to manage stateful information.

And the javadocs for [io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html) in the version `4.0` which apparently replaces version 3.x's `org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext` states the following for `Storing stateful information`

> **Storing stateful information**
>
> [AttributeMap.attr(AttributeKey)](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/AttributeMap.html#attr%28io.netty.util.AttributeKey%29) allow you to store and access stateful information that is related with a handler and its context. Please refer to [ChannelHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html) to learn various recommended ways to manage stateful information.

It seems that `Attachments` of version 3.x are now handled using [Attribute<T>](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/Attribute.html) (`generics` instead of `Object`!) in version 4.0

So you need to do look at [AttributeMap.attr(AttributeKey)](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/AttributeMap.html#attr%28io.netty.util.AttributeKey%29) and the example which states

> // This handler will receive a sequence of increasing integers starting from 1.

given there in the javadocs for `ChannelHandlerContext` in both versions.

I hope this will help you find a way for coding your requirements using the new API.

Comment: Great it worked. I'm having one more issue, it was the main reason that I wanted to switch to the new API to see if anything was wrong.
The client doesn't stay connected to server. I don't know why.

Comment: @PointyStorm well, this is another question on which I unfortunately cannot help :( . You might want to close this one and post another question with a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) in order to help you solve your issue.